# How to create a custom login action in Liferay 5.2.3 with a hook

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, liferay, hook

I am using Liferay 5.2.3 and I need to make a HOOK for LinkedIn integration (something similar with the `LinkedInSignIn-hook` in `Liferay 6`).

They have the `LinkedInSignInAction` class that extends `BaseStrutsPortletAction`, which is unavailable in Liferay 5.

My question is: how do I manipulate the data that results from the open authentication protocol inside a Java class?

Comment: please consider upgrading from a version that is now ~5 years old and completely unmaintained.

Comment: At the moment we cannot do such a thing, so I must keep struggling with Liferay 5.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hook into liferay you need to create a `liferay-hook.xml` file.  Here you map whatever the class is that gets used to the one that you intend to use.  So something like...

```
<service> 
    <service-type>com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService</service-type> 
    <service-impl>uk.co.myproj.meh.CustomLocalService</service-impl> 
</service>
```

Then, to make sure it still has the same functionality as before, extend the wrapper class of what you want to override, say UserLocalServiceWrapper then @Override any methods you intend to change the functionality of.  Bear in mind it's much better to do this and hook into portal-impl.jar classes than including the jar as it's bad practice to have a dependency an on implementation jar.

Comment: *don't* copy the whole original implementation. Rather extend `UserLocalServiceWrapper` and override the methods you want to override. `UserLocalServiceWrapper` implements all its methods as delegation to the original - unless you override. Typically, you want to call super.doSomething() as well.

Comment: Ah sorry that's exactly right. The child class should just override the methods it needs from the wrapper as the wrapper exists outside of the portal-impl.jar. I'll update the answer.